# AngularJS - $scope corrupted?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

a simplified version of my code

controller:

```
module.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, myService){
    $scope.isToggleActive = false;
    $scope.toggle = function() {
        $scope.isToggleActive = !$scope.isToggleActive;
    };
    myService.getData().then(function(data){
        $scope.number = data.number
        $scope.items = data.items;
    });
});
```

service:

```
module.factory('myService', function(JsonService, $q){
    function getData() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        JSONService.getJSON(url)
            .success(function(data) { deferred.resolve({number: data.number, items: data.items}); })
            .error(function(data) { deferred.reject(data); });
        return deferred.promise;
});
```

html:

```
<h1>{{number}}</h1>
<div id="tglbtn" ng-click="toggle()"></div>
<div id="toggle" ng-show="isToggleActive">
<span ng-repeat="item in items">{{item.text}}</span>
```

the jsonservice uses the $http to get the data from a rest service.

as long i've the myService.getData()... line in my code, interestingly the number int he headline gets applied, but instead of the expected multiple span items, there is just a comment of an ng-repeat, the toggle-div is visible and clicking the tglbtn doesn't toggle the visibility of it.

when setting a breakpoint into the callback, then $scope.number and $scope.items have the expected values. so i thought i'm missing an $apply or $digest. but doing so, results in an error that there is already a digest in progress.

if i remove that myService.getData()... line, then the toggle-div is not visible and the toggle click works.

i get no warnings or errors in the console :(

thanks for any help!

Comment: What is `getData`? Is `getMatchListEdition`? I don't see it in your code: am I missing something?

Comment: sorry. i updated the name of the service's function

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the number to some default value first in the controller.

```
$scope.number = 0
```

Otherwise the variable is not available when the view is generated and it causes an error. In your code the $scope.number gets to exist only after the promise from the $http call gets resolved. The same with items.

It is strange that you dont get no error in the console. Are you using strict mode ('use strict')?